Elastic Stack - Logstash gives JSON parse error
I am trying to create a logging service using the elastic stack.
I receive input in TCP (Input comes from different microservices) and based on the log logstash outputs to either http or elastic (or both).
I have some very large logs that also require filtering to adjust to JSON format, and one of them gives me the following json parse error:
JSON parse error, original data now in message field {:message=>"Unexpected end-of-input: was expecting closing quote for a string value\n at [Source: (StringReader); line: 1, column: 9560693]", :exception=>LogStash::Json::ParserError.
this is the logstash.conf file:
input{

    tcp {
        port => 5000
        codec => json
    }
}
filter{
    if [system] == 'nostro' {
        if [event] == 'state_snapshot' {
            json {
                source => "state"
                target => "current_state"

            }
            mutate { remove_field => ["state"] }

            # Separate state fields
            ruby {
                code => '
                    current_state = event.get("current_state")
                    if current_state.is_a?(Hash)
                        current_state.each do |key, value|
                            if value.is_a?(Array)
                                parsed_arr = value.map { |item| JSON.parse(item) rescue item}
                                event.set("[current_state][#{key}]", parsed_arr)
                            elsif key.include?("orders") && value.is_a?(Hash)
                                parsed_orders = value.transform_values { |json_string|         JSON.parse(json_string) rescue json_string }
                                event.set("[current_state][#{key}]", parsed_orders)
                            end
                        end
                    end
                '
            }

            mutate { rename => { "current_state" => "state" } }
        }
    }
}
output{
    # Condition the output index on the incoming logs 'system' field
    if [system] == 'nostro' {
        # Send to telegram if log is error
        if [log_level] in ['ERROR', 'CRITICAL'] {
            http {
                url => "http://host.docker.internal:8000/telegram-notification"
                http_method => "post"
                headers => {
                    "Content-Type" => "application/json"
                }
                message => ""
                automatic_retries => 1
                retry_failed => false

            }
        }
        if [event] == 'state_snapshot' {
            http {
                url => "http://host.docker.internal:8000/log-to-s3"
                http_method => "post"
                headers => {
                    "Content-Type" => "application/json"
                }
                message => ""
                automatic_retries => 2
                retry_failed => false

            }
        }
        elasticsearch {
            hosts => ["http://elasticsearch:9200"]
            index => "%{system}-%{service}-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"

        }
    }
    else if [system] == 'riskmanagement' {
        elasticsearch {
            hosts => ["http://elasticsearch:9200"]
            index => "riskmanagement-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"

        }
    }
    else {
        elasticsearch {
                hosts => ["http://elasticsearch:9200"]
                index => "other_index"

            }
    }
    stdout{codec => rubydebug}
}

I tried using only the http output for the same large log, and it works.
I also tried to make the log a shorter but in the same format (Some fields in the json are arrays or hash with a lot of keys, so I just deleted most of the values but kept some for parsing checking) and it works just fine.

It looks like the problem is the TCP buffer size.
This topic recommends playing with the net.ipv4.tcp_rmem and net.ipv4.tcp_wmem settings in the Logstash OS
